# libGL.so, libGLU.so and libglut.so are not found in the standard path

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am trying to compile and run a program using code block in c++. simple example for openGL that includes .When i try to setup code block the linker settings
i couldn't found libGL.so file inside my /usr/include directory

Comment: Which operating system? You should look for `libGL.so*` inside `/usr/lib/` (or  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` on some Debian related distributions) or `/usr/local/lib` on Linux.... A `/usr/include` directory should contain header files, not libraries.

Comment: What is the question...?

Comment: And you don't need Code Block, you need to type a command in a terminal. Once that works, you may configure your IDE to have it running appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/include` directory is for header files only.

The libraries are picked up from a standard set of directories (which is distro specific) but these are the common ones:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/lib64
/lib
/lib64
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib64
```

In addition the library paths can also be specified to the linker (`ld`) using the `-L` command line option (which is what IDEs usually do when you configure the linker settings).

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/include` contains header files only.

The corresponding libraries are usually stored in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: I am in ubuntu 12.04. inside /usr/local/lib no libGL.so or any other .so file

Comment: @realtekme: There are a number of other library directories. But honestly, you don't have to care. Just specify the libraries to use by their name, i.e. `-lGL -lGLU -lglut`. You don't need the full path; heck you even should not use the full path!